# round function in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, rounding

i have a query which rounds the value for the particular column name:

```
  select round([CIMtrek_CI_Act],0) as CI FROM [CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse]
```

where [CIMtrek_CI_Act_33] is not null and CIMtrek_CIMtrekUniqueID = 1917

and the reulst is

```
CI
1
```

but when i execute the following query :

```
(SELECT  (SELECT [T1].[CIMtrek_CIMtrekUniqueID]  AS [CIMtrek_CIMtrekUniqueID]
,round([T1].[CIMtrek_CI_Act],0)   AS [CIMtrek_CI_Act]
 FROM [CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse] T1 
 WHERE T1.CIMtrek_CIMtrekUniqueID = 1917 
 FOR  XML PATH('Record'), TYPE )) FOR XML PATH('Root')
```

the result is

```
<Root>
  <Record>
    <CIMtrek_CIMtrekUniqueID>1917</CIMtrek_CIMtrekUniqueID>
    <CIMtrek_CI_Act>1.000000000000000e+000</CIMtrek_CI_Act>
  </Record>
</Root>
```

the value is not rounded.

if the value is `10.58` than i have to get `11`. Also the field is `varchar` if there is no value i have to get `empty` string than `0`.

what is the mistake i have done here and how to fix the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rounded. What you see is the XML textual representation of SQL Server's `float`.

If you don't like that, cast it to an integer after rounding.

```
cast(round([T1].[CIMtrek_CI_Act],0) as int)
```

Comment: if there is value it prints without any problem if not it prints `0` `0` should not come if there is no value, How to do this.

Comment: `case when [T1].[CIMtrek_CI_Act] = '' then '' else cast(cast(round([T1].[CIMtrek_CI_Act],0) as int) as varchar) end`

Comment: Thanks it helped to find and fix my problem